# Dose Flutter support both scenedelegate and sirishortcut?

Tags: ios, objective-c, flutter, siri, sirishortcuts

I am trying to make an app to use siri shortcut in flutter.
But it does not work. What I want to do is try to show iOS screen from flutter to use the MethodChannle and ivokeMethod. when can move I also register siri short cut.

Implementing the code to MethodChannel&invokeMethod in AppDelegate.
it works.

When I added to SceneDelegate in my project, it crushed and showed these errors

Error is

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method sample/aaa on channel sample/aaa)

#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:7)
```

```
#1      _MyHomePageState._launchNativeScreen (package:flutter_to_ojt/main.dart:36:5)
```

Why I added to SceneDelegate is implement the siri short cut code in it.
I think it is caused by SceneDelegate because when I build the app only AppDelegate, it worked.

let me write down the my code

・flutter

```
'''class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
MethodChannel _channel = const MethodChannel('sample/aaa');


Future _launchNativeScreen() async {
await _channel.invokeMethod('sample/aaa');} //MethodChannle to Xcode

enter code here
@override Widget build(BuildContext context) {

var listItem = ["one", "Two", "three"];
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
   
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (BuildContext cotext, int index) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration (
        border: Border (
          bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.black38),
        ),
      ),
      child: ListTile(
        leading: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios_sharp),
        title: Text('$index'),
        subtitle: Text('&listItem'),
        onTap: () { _launchNativeScreen();
          print('ここまできてる');  },
      ));},
      itemCount: listItem.length,
  ), 
);}}

'''
```

・Xcode in AppDelegate

```
'''
@interface AppDelegate()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController *navigationController;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate
FlutterResult _flutterResult;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
printf("AppDelegate");

[GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];
[self setiOSChannel]; //connect to flutter
Override point for customization after application launch.

return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];}

- (void) setiOSChannel {
printf("setiOSChannel");

FlutterViewController * flutterController =(FlutterViewController*)self.window.rootViewController;

//setup navigation
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:flutterController];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
[self.window makeKeyWindow];

FlutterMethodChannel * methodChannle = [FlutterMethodChannel methodChannelWithName:@"sample/aaa" binaryMessenger:flutterController.binaryMessenger];

 [methodChannle setMethodCallHandler:^(FlutterMethodCall * call, FlutterResult result) {
   if ([call.method isEqual: @"sample/aaa"] ) {
        printf("sample/aaa");
        //push遷移ボタンコード
        UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName: @"Main" bundle: nil];
        UIViewController* vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MeasureViewController"];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
      printf("push遷移");


    }
}];}
'''
```

・Xcode in SceneDelegate

```
'''enter code here
@interface SceneDelegate () @end
@implementation SceneDelegate
- (void)scene:(UIScene *)scene willConnectToSession:(UISceneSession *)session options:(UISceneConnectionOptions *)connectionOptions  API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.0)){

printf("willConnectToSession");
NSUserActivity * act = [connectionOptions.userActivities.allObjects firstObject];

if (act != nil){
    _sirishortcut = YES;
      [self scene:(UIScene *)scene continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)act];
}

- (void)sceneDidDisconnect:(UIScene *)scene  API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.0)){
}

- (void)sceneDidBecomeActive:(UIScene *)scene  API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.0)){
}

- (void)sceneWillResignActive:(UIScene *)scene  API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.0)){
}

- (void)sceneWillEnterForeground:(UIScene *)scene  API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.0)){
}

- (void)sceneDidEnterBackground:(UIScene *)scene  API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.0)){
}

- (void)sceneDidEnterBackground:(UIScene *)scene  API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.0)){
}

- (void)sceneDidEnterBackground:(UIScene *)scene  API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.0)){
}
enter code here
- (void)scene:(UIScene *)scene continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity  API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.0)){

//storyboard取得
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName: @"Main" bundle: nil];

//storyboardID指定
UIViewController* vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MeasureViewController"];

//画面遷移のアニメーションを設定
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

//UINavigationControllerに向けてモーダル遷移
//[[self window presentViewController:nc animated:YES completion:nil];

//モーダル遷移
 [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion: nil];}'''
```

・Xcode in info plist

```
'''enter code here
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN""http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0"><dict>
<key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
<dict>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                <string>SceneDelegate</string>
                <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                <string>Default Configuration</string>
                <key>UISceneStoryboardFile</key>
                <string>Main</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>flutter_to_ojt</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
<string>????</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
<key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
<true/>
<key>NSUserActivityTypes</key>
<array>
    <string>DoscaleIntent</string>
</array>
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>LaunchScreen</string>
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
<string>Main</string>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

What do you think?

Comment: Hey, have you find any solution?